# Handle properties in onCreate() Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the need of creating an object as a property in my Kotlin class like this in Java:

```
class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private Dialog myDialog;
    //...
```

After the application context is ready, i can instanciate the `dialog` object

```
@Override
void onCreate(...){
//... super
dialog = MyDialogFactory.build(getApplicationContext, "Title", "Message").show();
```

I know that in Kotlin the properties must be initializated or become abstract, therefore my Kotlin class looks like this:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    private dialog = myDialogFactory.build(getApplicationCOntext, "title", "Message")
//...
```

The below code will have a RuntimeException because the context of the application is not ready at this point. So i have to initialize this object in the `OnCreate` method but then, the object would be available only local (in the function).

How can I solve this? I need the `dialog` object to become globally available in the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple fix:

```
 private lateinit var dialog: Dialog
```

then in the `onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle)` method:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle){
   super.onCreate(saveInstanceState)
   
   dialog = myDialogFactory.build(getApplicationCOntext, "title", "Message")
}
```

You can read more [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables)

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you so much! I'm relatively new to Kotlin and some folks recomended using `var dialog : Dialog? = null` but this is so elegant!